# How to launch "Removed icon application" (Android)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I was removed icon applicaion like this -> http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/removing-app-icon-launcher

But I can't launch it from my applicaion by my luanch Intent...

```
Intent launchIntent =
pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ittipon.test");
launchIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
getContext().startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Its NullPointerException occur,
How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
launchIntent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setClassName("com.ittipon.test",
"com.ittipon.test.YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("com.ittipon.test",
"com.ittipon.test.YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME"));
this.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

or

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().
getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ittipon.test");    
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: I try 1st then new problem occur "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]"

Comment: OK, Now it work I fix it by add <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> to <intent-filter></intent-filter>

Answer (score 0):

you can use broadcast receiver for a particular event like: TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK and from that receiver start your launcher activity using intent. 
In my case when user makes a calls on 999 then broadcast receiver is called and from that launcher activity is launched